# Problem local drupal 8/9 install civicrm: folder is not writable (on Windows)

Tags: drupal, installation, windows, local

I am a volunteer from a non-profit organization that has problems with the installation of civicrm. We already have civicrm in worpress on an Aruba host (and it works), but we wanted to move to drupal.

I understand that I have to install locally first and then transfer everything to my site (is that right?).

I tried to install CIVICRM locally via XAMPP and Composer on my Windows computer following the documentation (https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal8/).

When I get to the "Run the installer" step, I navigate to "Extend" and click on install the "CiviCRM Core" module.

I get the following error:
CiviCRM: System: The settings file "C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ drupal \ sites / default \ civicrm.settings.php" cannot be created. Ensure the parent folder is writable.

I tried to change the permissions and check the installation steps, but obviously something is wrong (due to my ignorance :/ )

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On windows use `attrib -r C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\default` to make it writable.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer of @Dermerit worked.

Just need to fix the `Read-only` property. Before I could find this answer, I endlessly - changed file permission of `Autenticated Users` to Add more Permissions -
`Full Control` , `Modify` and `Write`

But, it did not worked, then, I changed the file permissions for Users - added more permission for `User` -

`Full Control` , `Modify` and `Write` - but again this did not worked. And, when the `\sites\default` folder did not worked, I went above the folders root, tried with them, maybe - somewhere the error could exist with file-permission.

But again did not worked, or - `Configuration`  permission by anonymous Users did not worked either.

As, I was using Apache, for my setup the full working command is -

`attrib -r C:\Apache24\htdocs\domn04\sites\default`